# exe icons loading slowly after Installing Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

I just did a fresh install of Windows 8.1. When I go into explorer or any folder, the icons for all of my exe files display really slowly, causing the program to slow down considerably. I've never had this happen before. Does anyone know what causes that and how to fix it? Thanks.

I tried cleaning my disk, defragmented, and also tried rebuid my icon cache. but nothing helps

Comment: How many reallocated sectors does your hdd have?

Comment: @Ramhound Nothing..

Answer (score 0):

You should check the "Always show icons, never thumbnails" in folder options.
[image]